# Why my SOQL is not working in data loader?

Tags: visualforce, soql, community, data-loader

```
Select Id, CreatedDate, BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c, BMCServiceDesk__state__c, BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c, BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c 
        FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c  
        WHERE BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Resolved' OR BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Closed'AND CreatedDate > 2015-06-01T01:02:03Z 
              AND BMCServiceDesk__Status__c = 'TRUE'AND BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c LIKE '%Operations%'
```

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with my code. Thanks

Error 
[image]

Comment: Hi Dananjaya,
Is your query not returning any records or giving some error ?
If yes,could you please provide the error details.

Comment: Hi added a picture of my error

Comment: I have also had issues with entering in a custom query in DataLoader. Ultimately, I stopped trying that. Now, I export the columns I want, and use Excel to filter our what I don't want.

Comment: Would recommend using workbench to debug this adding each filter on one by one with a limit 100 until you have all of your filters on. In terms of the date format, I would try and use date literals instead of concrete dates: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of places where AND is glued to the preceding word?

Comment: Hi, I could not see that though. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Did that solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry Still have the same

Comment: can you send me the corrected soql query?

Comment: @DananjayaPathirana - What Adam is trying to say is there is no space between the words i.e. `!= 'Closed'AND` should be `!= 'Closed' AND` - sup Adam!

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it should be like this `WHERE BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Resolved' AND BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Closed'` not like this WHERE `BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Resolved' OR BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c != 'Closed'`You cannot put OR I guess, for me it will give me the same error even i correct the spaces.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Switching OR for AND fundamentally changes the nature of your query...

Comment: I am not sure about it. When I take out the "OR" and put "AND" it works. Otherwise it will give me errors.  I have no idea why tho.

Comment: Can you update the question with both SOQL queries, the one that's working and the one that isn't?

Answer (score 0):

SOQL is not very good at figuring out operator precedence if you mix AND and OR, so you need to include brackets.

For example

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'a' OR LastName = 'b' AND Title = 'Mr'
```

Is an invalid query. But both bracketed forms are legal:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'a' OR (LastName = 'b' AND Title = 'Mr')

SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (FirstName = 'a' OR LastName = 'b') AND Title = 'Mr'
```

So put appropriate brackets into your query, then it should be fine.